# Can I send logout request to radius server with radius client?

Tags: python, ruby, linux, radius, freeradius

There is one pptp server and I use radius server for authentication. Sometimes the vpn client is off line with unknow reason , so the radius can not clear the session for client.

I want to run one process with radius client to monitor the client, if the client has no heartbeat, the process will send logout request to radius server for client.

So i want to know what is the logout request message in radius client?

Comment: Can u use capital letters to start sentences and for "I" plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged your question with several languages.

Assuming you would like to do this in Python, you can use [Pyrad](http://www.wiggy.net/code/pyrad/) and use one of the method from `pyrad.packet`.